# How to make a webservice call synchronous in meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor, node-fibers

I am trying to call a simple weather service synchronously in meteor. I am not even able to make the client creating synchronous. In the code below I expect user.testData to contain "test data" but it contains nothing.

```
    if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.confirmWeather.onRendered(function(){
        var validator = $('.confirmWeatherAndGoToMessage').validate({
            submitHandler: function(event){
    Meteor.bindEnvironment(Meteor.call('testWeather',Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(error,result)
                {
                    if (error)
                    {
                        console.log(error.message)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var userId = Meteor.userId();
                        var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: userId});
                        if (user.testData)
                        {
                            console.log(user.testData);
                        }
                    }
                })));


            }
        });
    });

}


if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.methods({
        testWeather: function () {
            var soap = Npm.require('soap');
            var options = {
              ignoredNamespaces: {
                namespaces: [],
                override: true
              }
            }
            var url = 'http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?WSDL';
            Meteor.wrapAsync(soap.createClient(url, options,Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(err, client) {
                if (err)
                {
                    console.log("CREATE ERROR:");
                    console.log(err);
                }
                else
                {
                    Meteor.wrapAsync(Meteor.call("insertIntoTestData","test data",function(err,res)
                    {
                        if (err)
                        {
                            throw new Meteor.Error("server-error",error.message);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            console.log('DATA: ');
                        }
                    }));
                }
            })));
        },
        insertIntoTestData: function(data) {
            var userId = Meteor.userId();
            var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: userId});
            if (user)
            {
                return resultId = Meteor.users.update({_id:userId},{$set:{testData:data}});
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: are you trying to change the async call between your meteor client and meteor server to synchronous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't make that approach work maybe i can offer alternative. When i needed sync calls with request library i used different approach by using future library from fibers/future nodejs. After the request i just put "future.wait()" and inside async code callback "future.return(value)". Execution would then wait until request was finished and returned a value.
This link here nicely explains use of that approach also: https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/synchronous-methods

Best regards,

Dino

Comment: Hi Dino, your kung fu is strong! I tried your suggestion. It works like a charm. Thanks a ton.